# NDSolve Equation or list of equations expected instead of False in the first argument

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to find numerical solutions to system of equations

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}y''(t)=1+y'(t)\sqrt{\left[x'(t) \right ]^2+\left[y'(t) \right ]^2}\\ x''(t)=-x'(t)\sqrt{\left[x'(t) \right ]^2+\left[y'(t) \right ]^2}\end{matrix}\right.$$

with some arbitrary initial conditions. I tried:

```
NDSolve[{x''[t] + Sqrt[(x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2]*(x'[t]) == 0, 
y''[t] - Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2]*y'[t] - 1 == 0,x[0]==1,y[0]==1,x'[0] == 1, 
y'[0] == 1}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

however I get an error:

> Equation or list of equations expected instead of False in the first argument

and I can't figure out where is the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Restart your kernel and try again.

Comment: Always make sure that symbols used in equations are not assigned some value (`OwnValue`). E.g. Put `Clear[x,t,y]` before the equations to ensure this.

Comment: @zhk - Thank you. That was embarrassingly easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely that you have previously defined `x`, `y`, or `t` as a function or variable, meaning that those values were substituted into the equations which could apparently be simplified down to a true or false value, which `NDSolve` naturally cannot solve as an equation.

Try restarting your kernel, `Clear[x,y,t]`, or ``` Clear["Global``*] ``` (with only one `, due to formatting issues).